# What video players/sites are fully accessible?

Tags: web-app, accessibility

I am in need of a video player that is fully accessible, but I'm hoping not to have to code it from scratch.

How accessible are the youtube/vimeo players? are there other ones pre-made online that will work well in that respect?

Basically I'm looking for something that is keyboard accessible and can support some kind of closed captioning

I hope this is appropriate to this site, if not please let me know. I have been looking around and not finding a lot of good info on this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do you mean by "fully accessible"? That it complies with WCAG / Section 508 / WAI-ARIA? Or that it's actually fully accessible to everyone? Or that it has basic accessibility features? Which specific features do you require?

Because if you're just looking for a player that is Section 508 compliant, then [this business.gov page](http://www.business.gov/about/features/508-video-player.html) shows you how to embed one. So as long as the video has closed captioning, it's 508 compliant.

There's also [Easy YouTube](http://icant.co.uk/easy-youtube/). But I think this was created before YouTube became 508 compliant.

**Edit:**
According to [this page](http://www.learningport.us/organizations/?organization_id=275), the Vimeo player is also 508 compliant, so either player should work.

Comment: I'm not completely sure, I guess, what would be wanted out of a video player as I'm not an expert in accessibility or disabilities.  508 would be a good baseline I guess, I do not know a lot about it, tbh.  I imagine keyboard accessibility and ability to embed closed captions would be the main ones.

Comment: @Damon - if you don't know what you are asking for, how can anyone answer the question? You ask for an accessible player, but then you say you don't know what being accessible means.

Comment: i updated the question to indicate that i'm concerned with closed caption support and keyboard control